# How to determine if a full name has a space in it?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a field that a user can input first and last name to fill out my form. Sometimes, users put on their first name and that results in empty fields in my database. PLEASE keep in mind that I cannot change this method completely because this form is part of a bigger project and it is being used by other websites of my company.

This is the part of the code that i need the validation around it. I already have a validation that ensures that the filed is not empty but I need on more to ensure that the field has two items in it separated by space.

```
<input name="fullname" class="fullname"   type="text" value="#fullname#" maxlength="150"/>
            <cfif fullname eq '' and check2 eq 'check2'>
            <br /><span style="color:red">*you must enter your full name</span></cfif>
```

The check2 eq 'check2' is checking if the form was submitted already to ensure a user submitting their data twice.

I thought of using regular expressions to do that but unfortunately I am not very familiar with how to use regx in CF9 and the documentation online through me off a bit.

I was also thinking to use "Find" or "FindOneOF", any thoughts on that?

Also, I am trying to avoid using JQ,JS etc, so please try to keep your suggestions based on CF code IF possible.

Any help or different suggestions on how to tackle this issue will be very appreciated.

Comment: ColdFusion would be server side validation. JavaScript would be client side validation.  Your form suggests that you want client side validation, not server side, but you want a ColdFusion solution. I don't get it.

Comment: i know what you are talking about. I just wanted to avoid JS. So if there is a way to do it without JS I'll take it. If you have another option please write your suggestion down :)

Comment: Actually, I see what you are trying to accomplish in your form.  You are outputting the form with data and displaying a message based on existing data.  Let me modify my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this for server side validation:

```
<cfscript>
TheString = "ronger ddd";
TheString = trim(TheString); // get rid of beginning and ending spaces
SpaceAt = reFind(" ", TheString); // find the index of a space

// no space found -- one word
if (SpaceAt == 0) {
    FullNameHasSpace = false;
// at least one space was found -- more than one word
} else {
    FullNameHasSpace = true;
}
</cfscript>

<cfoutput>
<input type="input" value="#TheString#">
<cfif FullNameHasSpace eq true>
    <p>found space at position #SpaceAt#</p>    
    <p>Your data is good.</p>
<cfelse>
    <p>Did not find a space.</p>
    <p>Your data is bad.</p>
</cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Thank you this looks good. I'll try it and let you know in a second

Comment: I edited this a bit after I tested it.  This should work just fine for finding a space in a string.

Comment: It worked. I had to modify the code to work with the rest of my code but the basic idea was there to help me out. Thank you!

Comment: As pointed out by Dave Anderson, `refind` is pointless when you're looking for a single static character.

If a variable is needed, you can just do: `FullNameHasSpace = find(" ",trim(TheString))`

Comment: Also, writing `<cfif booleanvar EQ true>` is entirely redundant - it's already a boolean so doesn't need comparison!

Comment: @PeterBoughton, sometimes being redundant helps with readability. Not everyone has a thousand years of experience and knows every shortcut. <cfif booleanvar EQ true> may be redundant, but it's absolutely clear to everyone what it means. The same is not true of <cfif booleanvar>.

Comment: If you don't understand `<cfif boolean >` then you shouldn't be working with code.

Comment: @PeterBoughton, that's one of the most arrogant and least helpful statements I have ever read on StackOverflow.

Comment: It's not arrogant. It's (arguably) flippant and perhaps disrespectful, but there's no [arrogance](http://www.chambersharrap.co.uk/chambers/features/chref/chref.py/main?title=21st&query=arrogant) there, (nor is there any in the following explanation).

Comment: Boolean is the simplest data type there is. If is the simplest conditional there is.

If anyone doesn't understand these two _fundamental concepts_ then they should educate themselves before outputting any more code - because without an understanding of the basics then how can they be comfortable working with more complex things?

Answer (score 4):

No regex is needed for this.  A slightly simpler solution:

```
<cfset form.fullname = "Dave " />
<cfif listLen(form.fullname," ") GT 1> <!--- space-delimited list, no need for trimming or anything --->
   <!--- name has more than one 'piece' -- is good --->
<cfelse>
   <!--- name has only one 'piece' -- bad --->
</cfif>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will save it for the next time I will need to do something like that.